# how should be var type used appropriately in c# ? I'm trying to write my first code using var

Tags: c#, var, static-typing

I am new to C# and I'm trying to write my first code using `var type` .
as you see below ,I make a array of `integers` (`arr1`) then I tried to make a new `var type` and refer my previous array (`arr1` --> `int[]`) to it . but it occurs some errors that say :

> Error CS0236  A field initializer cannot reference the non-static
> field, method, or property.

is there any helps or hints ?

```
   using System;
   class VarType
   {
       int[] arr1 = { 1, 2, 3 };
       var varType = arr1;
   }
```

thanks to helpful comment from Charlieface , I change my code to below it solves another error about another things , but the above error still remains ! what should I do about it ?

```
using System;
class VarType
{
    int[] arr1 = { 1, 2, 3 };
    public static void Main()
    {
        var varType = arr1;
    }
    
 }
```

Comment: You can only use `var` on local variables inside functions, not fields or properties of classes

Comment: could anybody answer to me instead of commenting ? thank you dear visitors!

Comment: First see this on variables: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/variables ;  

 Then see this on the use of `var`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/implicitly-typed-local-variables

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First up, `var` is not a type. It's a special keyword that tells the compiler to infer the type from the data.

So, the two following are equivalent ways of defining an array:

```
int[] arr1 = { 1, 2, 3 };
var arr2 = { 1, 2, 3 };
```

Both `arr1` and `arr2` are `int[]` in this example.

The issue with your code is that you're trying to define a field in the class `VarType` using the `var` keyword which cannot be used for a field.

Had you written it this way it would work:

```
class VarType
{
    void SomeMethod()
    {
        int[] arr1 = { 1, 2, 3 };
        var varType = arr1;
    }
}
```

---

The second example in your question failed because `Main` was declared `static`, but the array wasn't. It works if you do this:

```
class VarType
{
    static int[] arr1 = { 1, 2, 3 };
    public static void Main()
    {
        var varType = arr1;
    }
}
```

Or like this:

```
class VarType
{
    int[] arr1 = { 1, 2, 3 };
    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        var varType = arr1;
    }
}
```